# How can I install rjags on Ubuntu AMI on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, r

I installed the pre-built Amazon Machine Image with Rstudio Server provided by [bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/bioconductor-cloud-ami/) into a free micro instance on EC2.
Then I installed [JAGS (Just Another Gibbs Sampler](http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/) to use it via rstudio server.
To this end I simply used the Rstudio Server shell `sudo apt-get install jags` which worked well as far as I can tell (if I run it again, it tells me JAGS is up-to-date).

However, when I tried to install the package "rjags" which is the interface between Rstudio and JAGS via either `biocLite("rjags")` or `install.packages("rjags")`, it failed with the error message

```
checking for jags_version in -ljags... yes
configure: error: "JAGS module directory /usr/lib64/JAGS/modules-3 does not exist."
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rjags’
* removing ‘/home/ubuntu/R/library/rjags’
Warning in install.packages :
    installation of package ‘rjags’ had non-zero exit status
```

I checked in lib64 and, indeed, there's only the directory "jags" with "jags-terminal" as its content.

I'd be grateful for any pointers, I guess it's obvious that I've been enabled to do something beyond my understanding thanks to great tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as I gave up, I found [the answer](http://empty-moon-9726.heroku.com/blog/2012/02/11/r-jags-rjags-on-an-ec2-instance/).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev jags r-cran-rjags
```

Subsequently, `biocLite("rjags")` works well. As the post informs me though, JAGS will exhaust a micro instance quickly anyway, so I didn't try the way in Dirk Eddelbuettel's comment anymore.